# Assign generic function to function pointer struct memeber

Tags: c++, generics, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I have to assign the following member of a struct:

```
esp_err_t (*handler)(httpd_req_t *r);
```

As you can see, it is a function pointer. I have a <s>generic</s> template function that I would like to assign as `handler`:

```
template <class Tmsg>
esp_err_t HandleRpc(httpd_req_t *req){...}
```

I am assigning the `handler` member inside a <s>generic</s> template class, so I have a generic type argument `Tpayload`:

```
httpd_uri_t cfg = {
    ...
    .handler = HandleRpc<Tpayload>,
    ...
};
```

I get:

> expected primary-expression before '>' token

The issue lies in the fact that I can't pass a member method pointer (I.E. `esp_err_t (RpcServer::*)(...)`), but `RpcServer` is a <s>generic</s> template class (I.E. has a template with one generic parameter). So I thought that by creating a <s>generic</s> template function *outisde* the class (global scope?), and passing the `RpcServer` instance into that function, I would be able to retrieve my instance of `RpcServer<T>` and all would be well.

Here is the smallest amount of code I could come up with to reproduce the issue:

```
int main()
{
    
}

template <class T>
class RpcServer{
    public:
        void RegisterHandler();
};

struct HandlerInfo{
    void (*handler)();
};

template <class T>
void Handle(RpcServer<T> test)
{

}

template <class T>
void RpcServer<T>::RegisterHandler(){
    HandlerInfo info = {
        .handler = Handle<T>;
    };
}
```

Am I missing the obvious, or is what I am trying to do going to require some uglier trickery?

Comment: Nothing to do with what you're asking but just FYI these are called templates in C++. Generics is not a C++ term.

Comment: This is not a "generic function". This is a template. A template is not a discrete function, and it is not a discrete class. The term "generics" is used, with very similar syntax, in Java and C#, however C++ is not Java or C#, and works in fundamentally different ways. C++ templates are nothing, whatsoever, like Java or C# generics. It is important to understand how C++ templates work fundamentally here. In your example, "`HandleRpc`" is not a function, and therefore cannot have a function pointer that's pointing to it. `HandleRpc` is a template.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik AFAIK templates in C++ enable the compiler to "dynamically write" functions or classes for as many type parameters as needed. I understand that they are not the same as C# generics, but I'm still not understanding why this wouldn't work. Wouldn't `.handler = HandleRpc<Tpayload>` "create" a "discrete instance" of the template?

Comment: In order to understand "why this wouldn't work", you need to show a [mre] that anyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown*** then attempt to compile and reproduce your compilation error. The shown code is incomplete and is not sufficient to determine this. Note: this doesn't mean posting an entire program to Stackoverflow, but only the ***minimum*** necessary to reproduce the compilation error.

Comment: maybe `.handler = HandleRpc<Tpayload>,` should be maybe `.handler = HandleRpc<Tpayload>(),`  so that the template constructs an object or a class?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I have updated the question with a reproducible example as requested!

Answer (score 0):

```
struct HandlerInfo{
    void (*handler)();
};
```

`handler` is a pointer to a function that takes no parameters, and doesn't return anything. You can set this pointer to point to any function. As long as it takes no parameters, and doesn't return anything (its return type is `void`). There are no exceptions to this, this is how C++ works, it is a strongly-typed language.

```
template <class T>
void Handle(RpcServer<T> test)
{
```

This is a template for a function that takes one parameter. The type of the parameter is not material. The point is that ***every*** instance of this template will be a function that takes exactly one parameter, always.

In C++, a pointer to a function that has no parameters can only be set to point to such a function. You cannot set this function pointer to point to a function that takes one parameter, or two parameters, or ten parameters. It can only be set to a function that takes exactly zero parameters. That's because that's what the pointer points to.

If you were to change the template function so that it takes no parameters, then this would work, of course:

```
int main()
{

}

template <class T>
class RpcServer{
    public:
        void RegisterHandler();
};

struct HandlerInfo{
    void (*handler)();
};

template <class T>
void Handle()
{

}

template <class T>
void RpcServer<T>::RegisterHandler(){
    HandlerInfo info = {
            .handler = Handle<T>
    };
}
```

This compiles on gcc 10. ".member" initialization syntax has been supported by gcc for a long time, but it's only been standardized as of C++20, so other compilers may not support this syntax.

You could, if you wish, declare this to be a pointer to a function that takes an `RpcServer<int>` as its parameter:

```
struct HandlerInfo{
    void (*handler)(RpcServer<int>);
};
```

Now, you will be able to initialize it to point to such a function:

```
HandlerInfo info = {
    .handler = Handle<int>
};
```

`HandleInt` instantiates a function that takes such a parameter, so the types match exactly.

Or, alternatively, make `HandlerInfo` itself a matching template:

```
template <class T>
class RpcServer{
    public:
        void RegisterHandler();
};

template<class T>
struct HandlerInfo{
    void (*handler)(RpcServer<T>);
};

template <class T>
void Handle(RpcServer<T> )
{

}

template <class T>
void RpcServer<T>::RegisterHandler(){
    HandlerInfo<T> info = {
        .handler = Handle<T>
    };
}

int main()
{
    RpcServer<int> server;

    server.RegisterHandler();
}
```

(Note -- your code has other syntax errors; if they were fixed it would seem that, at first, the code would compie; but if an attempt was made to instantiate the templates, it would fail due to the type mismatch)